# How to display loading on dynamic render in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, loading

I want to add a loading section while the components are dynamically rendered. My master component is like this

```
const [permisions, setPermisions] = React.useState([])
async function runCheck() {
    setPermisions([])
    // some logic to populate the permissions array        
}

const renderedUserPerms = Object.values(permisions).map((perms) => {
    return (
        <UserPerms {...perms} />
    )
})
```

and on the return part of the component, it is like this:

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
  spacing={1}
>
   {renderedUserPerms}
</Grid>
```

I would like to add a loading while the rendering is happening. Based on the code, it is possible to know the length of the array of the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not enough to give you a proper solution, but I believe that you are trying to call an API, then update your state base on the response of the API. In that case you can wrap your parent component with the Suspense component.

```
  <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      spacing={1}>
       {renderedUserPerms}
    </Grid>
 </Suspense>
```

Read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html